# .load jQuery method with data parameter for Partial Razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, razor

I'm working with Razor pages and can't get my dto object in javascript map to a class in the model using the jquery .load function.

So, a user clicks on a button in the UI and the following javascript runs:

```
$('#btnGoToResults').click(function (e) {
    var dto = {
        ID: 1,
        CODE: 5
    };
    $('#divPerformanceResults').load('/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial', dto); // Gives error 400
}
```

I've tried the following as well without getting it to work:

```
$('#divPerformanceResults').load('/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial', JSON.stringify(dto)); // "works" since the code behind is hit but the dto values are 0
```

Also tried rewriting with ajax:

```
// Gives error 400
$.ajax({
    url: '/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial',
    data: JSON.stringify(dto),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#divPerformanceResults').html(data);
    }
});
```

This is the model I'm trying to map it to:

```
public class RequestResultModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CODE { get; set; }
}
```

It is the in-parameter for the method creating and returning the partial view which will contain all logic for filtering:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetResultsPartial(RequestResultModel dto)
{
    Results = new List<PerformanceResultModel>()
    {
        ...
    };
    return new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_PerformanceResults",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<List<PerformanceResultModel>>(ViewData, Results)
    };
}
```

The method works and the partial is rendered so all of that is good. It's just the dto I need to get working so I can filter the result list. I did get the following to work by switching the method parameter to an int but it's only one parameter, I'm going to need several inputs later.

```
$('#divPerformanceResults').load('/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial', 'ID=15'); // This works. Only one param though
```

Attached the chrome log as well if that gives anything:
[image]

It feels like I'm just missing something easy here but I can't find any answers online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After some more testing and research I ended up at:
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

Where I found out that there are tokens added to razor pages preventing posts without it.

SO you can either ignore the token validation on global level or by class level, example:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

Or you can do as I did in the following:

First of all, rename the method to OnPost instead of OnGet:

```
public PartialViewResult OnPostResultsPartial(RequestResultModel dto)
```

Then in the javascript call include the token like the following:

```
$('#btnGoToResults').click(function (e) {
    var dto = {
        ID: 1,
        CODE: 5
    };
    $('#divPerformanceResults').load('/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial', 
      { dto: dto, __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() });
}
```

And that is it! It now maps the javascript object correctly with the class in the pagemodel :) Hope this will help others out there!

Answer (score 0):

your first version of .load() was good, jquery load() method will do http post if it detects dto param as object:

```
$('#divPerformanceResults').load('/PerformanceSearch?handler=ResultsPartial', dto);
```

and then you can add [HttpPost] attribute to your Action to accept post methods

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult OnGetResultsPartial(WebApplication1.Models.RequestResultModel dto)
    {
```

Comment: Oh.. tried that before as well but it can't be added to Razor pages. I'm getting error:
'HttpPostAttribute' cannot be applied to Razor Page handler methods. Routes for Razor Pages must be declared using the @page directive or using conventions.